# Wait Until setTimeout is Complete Before Returning Value Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, delay

I'm making a simple dice game, and I have set up a function that will randomly generate numbers and display them very quickly to simulate a sort of die being rolled. The problem I'm having is that I want to wait until the simulation is complete before I return the value, but instead the value is returned right away. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Essentially I want rollDie() to wait for diceSimulation() to be complete before continuing.

```
function rollDie(){

     diceSimulation();
     var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
     return result;

}

function diceSimulation(){
     for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
         var random; 
         (function (i) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
             }, 50*i);
         })(i);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be for `diceSimulation` to return a `Promise` that resolves after `50 * 31` ms, and for `rollDie` to `await` it:

```
async function rollDie(){

  await diceSimulation();
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  return result;

}

function diceSimulation(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = random;
        }, 50*i);
      })(i);
    }
    setTimeout(resolve, 1530);
  });
}
```

Note that rather than `(function (i) {` inside the loop, you might consider just using `let` instead of `var`, it's far nicer to read and debug. (Using `var` has too many problems - best to use `const` or `let` instead, whenever possible.) It would also be more elegant to select `result` *once* inside `diceSimulation`, rather than on every iteration of the loop, and unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, better to assign to `testContent` rather than `innerHTML`:

```
const result = document.getElementById("result");
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    result.textContent = random;
  }, 50*i);
}
```

Live demo:

```js
async function rollDie() {

  await diceSimulation();
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  return result;

}

function diceSimulation() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        result.textContent = random;
      }, 50 * i);
    }
    setTimeout(resolve, 1530);
  });
}

rollDie();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: When I run this, the simulation still runs after I have displayed the result from rollDie(). It's almost like it waits till right after the result has been displayed to do the simulation

Comment: If you change the `i < 30` number, or the `}, 50 * i` number, you'll have to change the `1530` number appropriately - otherwise, `resolve` *should* be called after all timeouts in the `for` loop have finished. Actually, since the final action is the same as the loop action, why not leave out the final action entirely, and iterate from 0 to 30 instead of from 0 to 29?

Comment: I didn't change anything, just pasted it in and it was doing that. I see the result displayed and then I see the simulation. It looks like rollDie() is actually returning [object Promise] instead of a number as well.

Comment: In order to consume `Promises` you have to call `.then` on them (or `await` them, as in the answer). See edit, seems to work just fine to me

Comment: Hmmm I'm still having the problem. Does it matter that I'm calling rollDie() from another function? Do I have to do another await?

Comment: Like I said, in order to get the value from `Promises`, you must either call `.then` on the `Promise` or `await` it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call Because `rollDie` is asynchronous, if you want a call of the function to resolve to a value, you'll have to use one of the above methods

Comment: I think I have it figured out, I made my other function await rollDie() and its close to working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your expected result using a callback or a promise .
A simple example below shows how you can use promises as a solution :

```
let diceSimulation = () => {
console.log("Dice simulation complete");
};
let rollDie = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
resolve("Roll die is completed");
})

rollDie.then((message)=> {
    console.log(message);

    diceSimulation();
},
(fail)=> {

})
```